# My Track pad refuses to respond

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I have a Lenovo laptop and its trackpad refuses to respond sometimes after booting up. Same also happens for the scrolling function with the swipe of two fingers. I want to know if it's a software problem or hardware problem.

Comment: Run the Lenovo Diagnostics App and see if the touchpad is detected. It is part of the keyboard and keyboards are not too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a driver issue. Have you reinstalled your operating system recently?

Windows, Linux, and most operating systems can treat the track pad as a regular mouse without dedicated drivers, which is a good thing because it allows you to install the operating system itself without having to use an external mouse (or being limited to keyboard only).

So while basic operation as a mouse does not require a driver, anything more advanced, including two-touch scrolling and sensitivity tuning requires proper drivers.

Go to Lenovo's PC support site at https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/

Search for your *exact* model and browse drivers, there should be a touchpad driver. Install it and restart your computer.

Comment: I recently installed a firmware update from Lenovo itself through the windows update. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Are you saying that the intermittent touchpad occurred after the firmware update?  Is so then likely a hardware issue

Comment: Yeah, and I just downloaded the drivers for it and it works.